# Having trouble populating my drop down list from informix DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, list, drop-down-menu

Can't Populate the dropdown list . Can anyone help , possibly some tutorials on my mistakes? I don't understand exactly how to populate my datasource. Pretty new to C# or ASP.Net so go easy on me.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> _newList = new List<string>();
    if (TextBox1.Text != null)
    {
        OdbcDataReader MapResult; //Data Reader
        Database db = new Database(); 
        string lat = "";
        string sql = " SELECT 
                            informix.dbimg_mstr_rec.doc_path 
                       FROM 
                            informix.dbimg_mstr_rec 
                      WHERE 
                            informix.dbimg_mstr_rec.doc_key 
                                = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        try
        {

           MapResult = db.ExecQuery(sql, timeOut);
           if (MapResult.Read())
           {            
               lat = MapResult["doc_path"].ToString();               
               DropDown1.DataSource = _newList;
               DropDown1.DataTextField = "doc_path";
               DropDown1.DataValueField = "doc_path";
               form1.Controls.Add(DropDown1);
           } //end if
           MapResult.Close();
           db.CloseConnection();
           //end while
        }//end try
        catch (OdbcException ex)
        {
           errList.Add("[User] Error 109: " + ex.Message);
        } //end catch
        return;
     } //end if
     else
        return;
   }
```

Comment: You haven't put the results in `_newList` and you need to read up on SQL injection and use parameterized queries not SQL concatenation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually binding the dropdown anywhere in this code.  You need to do something like this:

```
DropDown1.DataTextField = "doc_path";
DropDown1.DataValueField = "doc_path";
DropDown1.DataSource = dr.ExecuteReader();
DropDown1.DataBind();
```

Alternately, you can do this all in your page markup by using a SqlDataSource control.

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataSet"
      ConnectionString="myConnString"
      SelectCommand="myStoredProcedure"
      >
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:MyDropDownList id="DropDown1" runat="server" DataSource="SqlDataSource1"
       DataTextField="COLUMN_NAME" DataValueField="COLUMN_NAME" />
```

Comment: When I add the dropdown1.dataBind() it gives me this error. "DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'doc_path'."}

Comment: also I'm using an informix DB if that helps.

Comment: The error shows that you're trying to bind a string to your DropDown (the result of your query). Try to bind the reader instead: DropDown1.DataSource = MapResult;

Comment: @freddy Thank you , I figured it out right before I came back to this page.